# Thermal conduction (Annulus, 2D): Missing boundary conditions

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, boundary-conditions

The thermal conduction problem, described in polarcoordinates can be solved

```
t1 = 2; \[CapitalDelta]\[Phi] = 40 Degree; r1 = 0.161; r2 = 0.201;  
U = NDSolveValue[
{   Derivative[1, 0 , 0][u][t, r, \[CurlyPhi] ] +Derivative[0, 0 , 1][u][t,r, \[CurlyPhi] ] == \[Lambda] Laplacian[u[t, r, \[CurlyPhi]], {r, \[CurlyPhi]},"Polar"]+ 50 Boole[(0 < \[CurlyPhi] < \[CapitalDelta]\[Phi])]- 0.025 (u[t, r, \[CurlyPhi]] - 20)
, u[0, r, \[CurlyPhi]] == 100, u[t, r, 0] == u[t, r, 2 Pi]},
u,{r, r1, r2}, {\[CurlyPhi], 0, 2 Pi}, {t, 0, t1}
, Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid"}}]
```

using `Methodof Lines` in an `TensorProductGrid`.

The solution

```
Quiet@Show[{Graphics[{Gray,Annulus[{0, 0}, r2 {1.05, 1.1}, {0, \[CapitalDelta]\[Phi]}], Line[{{0, 0}, {r2, 0}}],Line[{{0, 0}, r2 {Cos[\[CapitalDelta]\[Phi]], Sin[\[CapitalDelta]\[Phi]]}}]}],DensityPlot[U[#, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[x, y]] , {x, -r2, r2}, {y, -r2,r2}, ColorFunction -> ColorData["ThermometerColors"] ,ColorFunctionScaling -> True , PlotLegends -> Automatic, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, r1^2 < x^2 + y^2 < r2^2], PlotRange -> All, Exclusions -> None, Frame -> False]}] &[2]
```

[image]

looks fine

but NDSolve gives the message `NDSolveValue::bcart: Warning: an insufficient number of boundary conditions have been specified for the direction of independent variable r. Artificial boundary effects may be present in the solution.`

I tried  to add two flux boundaries `NeumannValue[0,r==r1]` and `NeumannValue[0,r==r2]` to the pde but it doesn't work. Unfortunately `Method->"FiniteElement"`  doesn't work.

My question: How can I avoid the error message and fullfill the two flux boundary conditions?

Thanks!

Comment: You did not define a $\lambda $. In the case of FEM, zero boundary conditions of Neumann type are automatically applied at boundaries $r=r_1,r_2$. So use `Derivative[0, 1, 0][u][t, r1, \[CurlyPhi]] == 0, 
Derivative[0, 1, 0][u][t, r2, \[CurlyPhi]] == 0`

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thank you very much, it works! I only tried the NeumannValue, but couldn't use FEM because of the periodicty condition.

Comment: FEM also works well in this case.

Comment: @ AlexTrounev Unfortunately not. If I substitute `TensorPorductGrid` by `FiniteElement` NDSolve doesn't evaluate. Or would you suggest another way?

Comment: What is lambda equal to?

Comment: The value is `lamda =0.5`

Comment: The 2D "MethodOfLines" with periodic boundary conditions gives a large error. See my answer on how to apply FEM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To solve the problem, we can apply FEM using explicit Euler in time. So that there were no messages, we organized a weak leak across the border.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]; t1 = 2; \[CapitalDelta]\[Phi] = 
 40/180 Pi ; r1 = 0.161; r2 = 0.201; \[Lambda] = 1/2; 
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{50 , 0 <= x <= \[CapitalDelta]\[Phi]}, {0, 
    True}}]; mesh = ImplicitRegion[r1^2 <= x^2 + y^2 <= r2^2, {x, y}];
t0 = 1/20; n = 40;
U[0][x_, y_] := 100;
Do[U[t] = 
   NDSolveValue[(u[x, y] - U[t - t0][x, y])/
       t0 - \[Lambda] Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] + (x D[u[x, y], y] - 
        y D[u[x, y], x]) - f[ArcTan[x, y]] + 0.025 (u[x, y] - 20) == 
     NeumannValue[10^-9 u[x, y], True], u, {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
    Method -> {"FiniteElement", InterpolationOrder -> {u -> 2}, 
      "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.001, 
        "MeshOrder" -> 2}}];, {t, t0, n t0, t0}]
Table[DensityPlot[Evaluate[U[t][x, y]], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> Row[{"t = ", t*1.}], 
  ColorFunction -> ColorData["ThermometerColors"], PlotPoints -> 100, 
  Frame -> False, ColorFunctionScaling -> True], {t, 10 t0, n*t0,10 t0}]
```

[image: Figure 1]
For comparison, we used the 1D model, given the absence of gradients along `r`. We see that the data is consistent with FEM.

```
With[{r = (r1 + r2)/2}, 
 U1 = NDSolveValue[{Derivative[1, 0][u][t, \[CurlyPhi]] + 
      Derivative[0, 1][u][
       t, \[CurlyPhi]] == \[Lambda] D[
         u[t, \[CurlyPhi]], {\[CurlyPhi], 2}]/r^2 + f[\[CurlyPhi]] - 
      0.025 (u[t, \[CurlyPhi]] - 20), u[0, \[CurlyPhi]] == 100, 
    u[t, 0] == u[t, 2 Pi]}, u, {\[CurlyPhi], 0, 2 Pi}, {t, 0, t1}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
       "MinPoints" -> 200, "MaxPoints" -> 200, 
       "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}}]]

Table[DensityPlot[
  Evaluate[U1[t, ArcTan[x, y]]], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> Row[{"t = ", t*1.}], 
  ColorFunction -> ColorData["ThermometerColors"], PlotPoints -> 100, 
  Frame -> False, ColorFunctionScaling -> True], {t, 10 t0, n*t0, 
  10 t0}]
```

[image: Figure 2]
Also, in version 12, we can use FEM and time dependency. The result completely coincides with that obtained using explicit Euler:

```
U12 = NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x, y], 
       t] - \[Lambda] Laplacian[
        u[t, x, y], {x, y}] + (x D[u[t, x, y], y] - 
        y D[u[t, x, y], x]) - f[ArcTan[x, y]] + 
      0.025 (u[t, x, y] - 20) == NeumannValue[10^-9 u[t, x, y], True],
     u[0, x, y] == 100}, u, {t, 0, t1}, {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
   Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
     "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.001}}];
Table[DensityPlot[Evaluate[U12[t, x, y]], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> Row[{"t = ", t*1.}], 
  ColorFunction -> ColorData["ThermometerColors"], PlotPoints -> 100, 
  Frame -> False, ColorFunctionScaling -> True, PlotRange -> All], {t,
   10 t0, n*t0, 10 t0}]
```

[image: Figure 3]

The 2D "MethodOfLines" with periodic boundary conditions in polar coordinates gives a solution that does not have physical meaning. For example, the code below has no messages (unlike the one suggested by Ulrich Neumann)

```
U2 = NDSolveValue[{Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][t, r, \[CurlyPhi]] + 
     Derivative[0, 0, 1][u][t, 
      r, \[CurlyPhi]] == \[Lambda] Laplacian[
       u[t, r, \[CurlyPhi]], {r, \[CurlyPhi]}, "Polar"] + 
     f[\[CurlyPhi]] - 0.025 (u[t, r, \[CurlyPhi]] - 20), 
   u[0, r, \[CurlyPhi]] == 100, u[t, r, 0] == u[t, r, 2 Pi], 
   Derivative[0, 1, 0][u][t, r1, \[CurlyPhi]] == 0, 
   Derivative[0, 1, 0][u][t, r2, \[CurlyPhi]] == 0}, 
  u, {r, r1, r2}, {\[CurlyPhi], 0, 2 Pi}, {t, 0, t1}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
      "MinPoints" -> 40, "MaxPoints" -> 100, 
      "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}]
```

Compare solution `U2` and solution `U1` (1D "MethodOfLines"). We see that in 2D the heat flux at the boundary $\phi =0=2\pi$ has a gap, which is devoid of physical meaning.

```
Plot[{U2[2, (r1 + r2)/2, phi], U1[2, phi]}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image: Figure 4]

We add the condition of equality of heat fluxes at the boundary $2\pi=\phi =0$. In this case, the solution has the form

```
U2 = NDSolveValue[{Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][t, r, \[CurlyPhi]] + 
     Derivative[0, 0, 1][u][t, 
      r, \[CurlyPhi]] == \[Lambda] Laplacian[
       u[t, r, \[CurlyPhi]], {r, \[CurlyPhi]}, "Polar"] + 
     f[\[CurlyPhi]] - 0.025 (u[t, r, \[CurlyPhi]] - 20), 
   u[0, r, \[CurlyPhi]] == 100, u[t, r, 0] == u[t, r, 2 Pi], 
   Derivative[0, 0, 1][u][t, r, 0] == 
    Derivative[0, 0, 1][u][t, r, 2 Pi], 
   Derivative[0, 1, 0][u][t, r1, \[CurlyPhi]] == 0, 
   Derivative[0, 1, 0][u][t, r2, \[CurlyPhi]] == 0}, 
  u, {r, r1, r2}, {\[CurlyPhi], 0, 2 Pi}, {t, 0, t1}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
      "MinPoints" -> 40, "MaxPoints" -> 100, 
      "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}]
```

Now we see an even greater difference between solutions of the equation obtained using 2D "MethodOfLines" and FEM (1D and FEM coincide on this scale).

```
Plot[{U2[2, (r1 + r2)/2, phi], U1[2, phi], 
  U12[2, Cos[phi] (r1 + r2)/2, Sin[phi] (r1 + r2)/2]}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> {"2D", "1D", "2D FEM"}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"\[CurlyPhi]", "u"}]
```

[image: Figure 5]

Comment: Thank you for your Help, I have to elaborate....

Comment: What do you mean with: "Now we see an even greater difference with 1D and FEM (1D and FEM coincide on this scale)." Do you mean ....with 2D (TPG) and FEM... ?

Comment: @user21 Thank you, corrected. I do not have version 11.3, but in version 12 this code works.